# How to access string from PHP to jQuery using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple registration form. What I want to achieve is when the output from PHP is `success` then do something. Else do something else. Both in AJAX. I hope you can help me because I am totally new in jQuery and AJAX

This is part of my PHP for this form:

```
if ($kontrolaMenoPocet != 0) {
    $error[] = "<p class='text_chyba'>Takéto meno už existuje!</p>";
}
if ($pocetZnakovNick > 15) {
    $error[] = "Nick môže mať maximálne 15 znakov!";
}
if ($kontrolaEmailPocet != 0) {
    $error[] = "<p class='text_chyba'>Takýto E-mail sa už používa</p>";
}
if ($pocetZnakovHeslo != 0 AND $pocetZnakovHeslo < 6) {
    $error[] = "Heslo musí mať minimálne 6 znakov";
}elseif ($pocetZnakovHeslo == 0) {
    echo "";
}
if ($heslo != $hesloZnova) {
    $error[] = "Hesla sa nezhodujú";
}
if (empty($error)) {
    //writte into database
}
if (isset($error)) {
    if (empty($error)) {
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        foreach ($error as $chyba) {
            echo $chyba;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my jQuery with AJAX:

```
if (nick == '' || email == '' || heslo == '' || hesloZnova == '') {
    $('.registracia_form .nick, .email, .password, .password_again').addClass('inputError');
} else {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'PHP/register.php',
        data: data,
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `.done()` callback to:

```
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data === 'Success') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, when there is error, use `http_response_code` function to set status code other than 200 so the `fail` function in ajax will be called.